# How to remove dangling files in s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently working on a product wherein if a file is uploaded using upload modal and user cancel/closes the modal without completing the entire process, then it becomes orphaned. It's not being used anywhere but I still have to store and maintain it forever on s3. These files need to be cleaned up either immediately or periodically, whatever makes more sense. Can someone suggest a way of handling such a scenario?

Eg. In the upload modal, the user first uploads the file, and then is supposed to enter some fields such as Name, etc. On uploading the file, it gets stored in s3. Now, if the user decides not to go ahead with the process (i.e. filling in the Name field, etc) and backs-off, then that file is still in s3.

PS: Files which are being used have their s3 URL stored in my database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for S3 lifecycle rules with some tags.

When user starts the upload, tag the just uploaded file as example with `PROCESSED: false`. Then create lifecycle rule which deletes files with tag `PROCESSED: false` after 5 days lets say.

Any process that user will finish needs also to update the tag to `PROCESSED: true`, so good files won't be deleted.

Lifecycle rules are available through the Management tab of your bucket settings. Example:

[image: Example of lifecycle rules]

Comment: I think my question was misunderstood. I have revised it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Nemin I still believe Lifecycle rules are a way to go. I have updated my answer, check the updated solution proposal.